# Using Custom font in kivy font thai

Tags: python, kivy

orginal text : 
[image]

display in kivy : 
[image]

I have tried adding font_size to Thai font.

Keep me informed

Answer (score 0):

Download the font for this language. And when you download, put the file in project file. And then below `text` type:

```
font_name: 'name of the file you downloaded'
font_size: 40      #size of the text duh
size: 50, 50       #you can try thos to resize them
size_hint: .1, .1  #this is more usable
```

Comment: I tried it and it just shows the characters in Thai. but can't solve where the letters overlap